# use of undeclared type or module `HttpResponse`: not found in this scope

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I must admit, I am having a hard time making sense of the Rust compiler error messages.

I have this module:

**src/adapters.js**

```
use actix_web::{Responder, HttpResponse};

pub mod Basic {

    pub fn api_index() -> &'static str {
        "API"
    }

    pub fn admin_index() -> impl Responder {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body("hello world!")
    }

}
```

The Rust compiler keeps telling me when I use

```
use crate::actix_web::{Responder, HttpResponse};
```

that:

```
E0432: unresolved import `crate::actix_web`  maybe a missing crate `actix_web`?
```

Rest assured, crate::actix_web is *not* missing, because I can run simple requests from main.rs. The problem starts when I want to use the actix_web modules within my own modules.

If I have

```
use actix_web::{Responder, HttpResponse};
```

Rust keeps teeling me:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `HttpResponse`

HttpResponse::Ok().body("hello world!")
^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope



help: consider importing one of these items
use actix_web::HttpResponse;
use crate::adapters::HttpResponse;


E0432: unresolved import `crate::actix_web`  maybe a missing crate `actix_web`?
```

I my main.rs, as the first line, I've also declared:

```
extern crate actix_web;
```

For the sake of making sure, I've also added "extern crate actix_web;" to the adapters.rs module right at the start. That didn't change anything either.

I am running out of options, I don't know what else I could possibly do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically You have created one another module Basic inside adapters module.So Basic is **submodule** of adapters module. So two ways you can access the external crate in this case.

1. Import external crate modules inside your Basic Module.

```rust
pub mod Basic {
    use actix_web::{Responder, HttpResponse};

    pub fn api_index() -> &'static str {
        "API"
    }

    pub fn admin_index() -> impl Responder {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body("hello world!")
    }
}
```

2. Or import an external module in outer module module and access those module using use super keyword in inner module.

```rust
use actix_web::{Responder, HttpResponse};

pub mod Basic {

    pub fn api_index() -> &'static str {
        "API"
    }

    pub fn admin_index() -> impl super::Responder {
        super::HttpResponse::Ok().body("hello world!")
    }
}
```